# What is the beejam of Lord Dakshinamurthy?

Tags: scripture, vedas, shiva, puranas, dattatreya

Every God and Goddess have their beejams. For example, Lord Dattatreya has beejam "Dram".

What is Lord Dakshinamurthy beejam?